# What's the meaning of 'Min' in The Old Curiosity Shop?

Tags: terminology, charles-dickens

In Dickens' *[The Old Curiosity Shop](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/700/700-h/700-h.htm),* the word 'min' is used. For example: "is the old min friendly?" As it is only used by one character, Mr Swiveller, one can assume it to be slang and expect it to mean 'man.'  Nevertheless, I cannot relate it to a London accent of any type, and I like to think I have qualification in saying that as a resident of London since birth.

I would like confirmation of my speculated meaning, or an explanation of what it means if it means something else.

Comment: Like Sumelic, I haven't yet taken the time to look into the original context, but another possibility is that Dickens was using eye-dialect to convey someone pronouncing *man* in some non-RP British accent. I have a vague and possibly incorrect recollection that Dickens used a lot of eye-dialect, especially for his characters which came from the lower classes.

Comment: 'I like to think I have qualification in saying that as a resident of London since birth.' If you were born before Dickens wrote this, I might agree.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , there may be truth in that, but the basics of the working class London accent have not changed too significantly. Also, note the 'I like to think'; a stab at humour if you will.

Comment: @OscarBrogden Admittedly, I haven't been to London in a while, but last time I was there, I didn't hear anyone speaking like the chimney sweep from *Mary Poppins*.

Comment: Also not claiming absolute truth here, could it be that min is used pejoratively here, in a 'that scoundrel' kind of way?  The Old English meaning appears to [mean](http://www.wordsense.eu/min/)(Origin and History II): *"From Middle English, from Old English min ("less", also "small, mean, evil, vile, harmful"), from Proto-Germanic *minniz ("less"), from Proto-Indo-European *(e)mey- ("small, little"). Cognate with Dutch min ("less, small"), Low German minn ("small, low, lean"), German minder ("less"), Icelandic minna ("less"), Latin minus ("less")."*.

Comment: @Dan - Who, incidentally, [went down in history](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/what-to-watch/worst-movie-accents/) for doing the worst Cockney accent in television history? I'd be more surprised if you *had* heard anyone like him...he'd be quartered on the spot by his countrymen!

Comment: Sidenote to my link to Wordsense: It appears they don't quite have their translations down. *'Less'* is *'Minder'* in Dutch, and in German, it's *'Weniger'*. I don't doubt the rest of the explanation is correct, but with one mistake made, there may be more.

Comment: Apologies for the spam, but I just found some [information](https://books.google.nl/books?id=B64RAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=min+dialect+for+man&source=bl&ots=cL5caPKdlK&sig=3onwrdH7z4iotusbPlVLmsiA6JE&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWg7qW2aXLAhVG_g4KHVvIBBEQ6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q=min&f=false) on English dialects where there's a sentence that goes *"The forms mun, men, min seem to have arisen through loss of stress"*. This would indicate that, in this context atleast, it does mean 'man'.

Comment: @Terah: the "less" sense of "min" seems to be only used as an adjective, at least according to that source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read Dickens, you have to keep in mind that the original format was as a serial publication, one chapter at a time, rather than as a single volume as we see his books.

This meant that as an author, Dickens faced the challenge of making the story easy to follow in serial form, and one way he did this was in characterisation. He gave his characters easily identifiable features, which has led to accusations (IMO unfair ones) that he had caricatures rather than characters. It could be physical like Mrs Sparsit's nose, mental like Gradgrind's utilitarianism, an accesory like Bill Sikes' dog, a speech characteristic like Mr Dorrit's "ha hum" or Uriah Heap's "Umble". Or it could be a dialect or accent.

As the aim was to make characters easily identifiable, it is unlikely that Dickens was faithfully recording any particular local dialect, though it is not imposible that he borrowed something he heard on the streets. It is probably better to view Mr Swiveller as having an idiolect.

For more depth, this is a good overview of [Dickens characters.](http://eprints.ibu.edu.ba/86/1/FLTAL%202011%20Proceed%C4%B1ngs%20Book_1_p565-p573.pdf)

Comment: So, what does "min" mean?

Comment: It doesn't 'mean' anything. It is just a variation in the pronunciation of 'man'. Asking what it means is like me (a non-rhotic Brit) asking an American what their rhotic  pronunciation of 'car' means.