# What is the meaning of ‘ leave me to mind ‘ here?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of ‘ leave me to mind ‘ here ?

It means leave me alone , or not ?

> “Strangers are nothing to me, grandfather,' said the young fellow catching at the word, 'nor I to them, I hope. The best they can do, is to keep an eye to their business and ***leave me to mind.*** There's a friend of mine waiting outside, and as it seems that I may have to wait some time, I'll call him in, with your leave.”

From The Old Curiosity Shop, chapter 2

Comment: It's a typo; *mind* s/b *mine.* https://textbase.scriptorium.ro/dickens/the_old_curiosity_shop/chapter_2

Comment: “But is the ' old min ' agreeable?' said Mr Swiveller in an undertone.”

What does ‘old  min’ mean here ?

Comment: Or it is "mine" in this online book. From the 2nd chapter: ‘Strangers are nothing to me, grandfather,’ said the young fellow catching at the word, ‘nor I to them, I hope. The best they can do, is to keep an eye to their business and leave me to mine. There’s a friend of mine waiting outside, and as it seems that I may have to wait some time, I’ll call him in, with your leave.’

Comment: Ok got it thanks.   “But is the ' old min ' agreeable?' said Mr Swiveller in an undertone.” What does ‘old min’ mean here ?

Comment: That's been asked here before. There's some speculation about it. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311389/whats-the-meaning-of-min-in-the-old-curiosity-shop

Comment: Thank you very much